# Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /usr/local/src/master/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:952)

Tags: php, laravel, runkit

1. PHP version :

```
PHP 8.1.23 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2023 21:56:29) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.23, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.23, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

2. runkit7 version: 4.0.0a6
   [image: Screen Shot 2023-10-20 at 15 48 28]
3. OS version and compiler version

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="aaaa:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

5. Problem is : runkit7_function_remove() is not working. 502 error occur in nginx error log.
   Sample code:

```
        $user = Auth::user();
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
        try {
          // Remove the function of laravel helper *__* function
          if (function_exists('__')) {
                runkit7_function_remove('__');
          }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
           Log::debug($e->message);
        }
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
        require(public_path() . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php');
```

6. **I want to remove laravel helper function because of Laravel helper function and WordPress function conflict.**

in wordpress: `__` function is in public/wp/wp-includes/l10n.php.[[link](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/l10n.php#L296)]

in laravel : `__`function is in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php [[link](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/3c888b6c7b89c3d3f90e9024ffbebed3ee80bd23/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L878)]

Comment: _"Problem is : runkit7_function_remove() is not working"_ What is it that doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Well, that nginx problem not an exception from your code ! otherwiser you'll see 500

Comment: @shingo I means that execution has be stop in line: runkit7_function_remove() function.

Comment: @PsyLogic Because of this case, nginx error occur with msg: [error] 28752#28752: *112 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: domain.jp, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "domain.jp"

Comment: You know it stopped in that line, so you must see an exception, right? What's the exception?

Comment: @shingo exception msg doesn't return any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to close the issue. Finally, I get the ans.

I edit the line WP's l10n.php
to before line of laravel's autoload.php calling in public/index.php

i.e: in Laravel's public/index.php,

```
require __DIR__. '/wp/wp-includes/l10n.php';

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```